# What do those sideways "L" in BBEdit's gutter area mean?

Tags: bbedit

Please see image below.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Those L-things :-) indicate the *end* of a foldable range of text (with the downward pointing triangle indicating the start).